# Compass plugins to work with GRUNT

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass-sass

Using terminal to compile my sass/compass works perfectly, Ive used it for a few projects now and have started using compass plugins within these projects. However I also need to start automating my projects using GRUNT but I havent been able to get compass plugins to work with the GRUNT sass plugin "grunt-contrib-sass".. I dont have to use this plugin its just the first I found - does anyone know how to get this to work or suggest another plugin?

> All help is very much appreciated..

---

• I want to use GRUNT to automate some tasks including the processing of my SASS/Compass.

> **Problem:**

• I have a compass plugin called "rgbapng" as seen in my config file that causes GRUNT to error out (as seen in the last image)

> **Question:**

• How to I get this compass plugin to work with GRUNTS "grunt-contrib-sass" - has anyone else done this - has anyone a suggested plugin that works better?

**Compass Config.rb file...**

[image: Config file for my sass/compass setup - works perfectly]

**The settings Im using in my grunt.js file for grunt-contrib-sass**

[image: grunt-contrib-sass setup im using]

**The Error im getting in returnwatch/**

[image: terminal error]

---

### UPDATE: updated grunt file now get a different error message see below

[image]
[image]

The last error was fixed by changing the paths in the gruntfile.js from /assets/ to assets/ .. however the scss now compiles with no errors but the plugin still doesn't work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### use grunt-compass, sass compiling is included.

Required plugins go in require array and import statements in your sass code.
Dont forget to install the gem you need.

```
compass:
  app:
    options:
      require: ['compass-h5bp', 'ceaser-easing'] #to use compass libs
      sassDir: 'assets/css'
      cssDir: 'assets/css'
      imagesDir: 'assets/img'
      fontsDir: 'assets/font'
      httpPath: "/"
      relativeAssets: true
      boring: true
      debugInfo: true
      outputStyle: 'compressed'
      raw: 'preferred_syntax = :sass\n'
```

js code:

```
compass: {
  app: {
    options: {
      require: ['compass-h5bp', 'ceaser-easing'],
      sassDir: 'assets/css',
      cssDir: 'assets/css',
      imagesDir: 'assets/img',
      fontsDir: 'assets/font',
      httpPath: "/",
      relativeAssets: true,
      boring: true,
      debugInfo: true,
      outputStyle: 'compressed',
      raw: 'preferred_syntax = :sass\n'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I still get the message "unreadable or file not found" - I used gem list rgbapng -i that equaled "false" o I guess the gem is not installed? but then it works without grunt and I ran the "gem install compass-rgbapng" with "sudo" have you got any ideas?

Comment: The sass now compiles but the plugin although listed doesn't work - I feel its not installed properly but do not know how to proceed.

Comment: what does `gem list` say ?

Comment: I just dumped all the gems to read down the list and found: "compass-rgbapng" but when I use require: 'compass-rgbapng' I get rb: cannot load such file -- compass-rgbapng
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

Comment: it is in gem list but with the name compass-rgbapng

Comment: watch out you must require "rgbapng" not " compass-rgbapng"

Comment: yep, thats whats confusing. when I require just rgbapng - sass processes properly but when I go to load the page it says "file not found rgbapng"

Comment: I guess that file not found is something else

Comment: Did you import it ?
In your sass file:
    @import "rgbapng"

Comment: yep - currently the terminal/grunt says its all compiled and with no errors but the page errors out "@import "rgbapng"; is in the sass files and is working if i dont use grunt..