# Import compass into SCSS

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass

How do I import compass into my SCSS so that I can make use of mixins etc.

I currently use grunt to generate my SCSS files, I'm not sure exactly how I could do this.

my watch task is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
   jade: {
      files: 'app/views/**/*.jade',
      tasks: ['jade']
    },
     css: {
        files: '**/*.scss',
        tasks: ['sass']
    }
}
```

and my sass task is:

```
module.exports = {
   dist: {

         files: [{
           expand: true,
           cwd: 'scss',
           src: ['**/*.scss'],
           dest: 'stylesheets',
           ext: '.css'
         }]
   }
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735910/compass-plugins-to-work-with-grunt

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Compass Grunt Task found here:

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass

Here's the example usage from the git repo:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  compass: {                  // Task
    dist: {                   // Target
      options: {              // Target options
        sassDir: 'sass',
        cssDir: 'css',
        environment: 'production'
      }
    },
    dev: {                    // Another target
      options: {
        sassDir: 'sass',
        cssDir: 'css'
      }
    }
  }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'compass']);
```